# SharePoint Designer Login Credential Request

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I downloaded SharePoint Designer 2013 64bit and it worked just fine.  However, the company is using MS-Office 32Bit.  So I uninstalled SPD 2013 64bit and installed the 32bit.  After doing so I'm constantly asked to login to MS-Office.  I'm already logged into MS-Office, and furthermore, it doesn't accept the login credentials I have anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to add my email domain under ->Admin ->SharePoint ->Site Collections ->My SharePoint sites.  Once that was done SharePoint stopped asking me for the login credentials.